# Coding style checker for C

Tags: c, coding-style

I'm working for a company that has strict coding style guidelines but no automatic tool to validate them. I've looked around and the only tools I could find were lint like tools that seem to be aimed at verifying what the code does, and preventing bugs and not at making sure the coding style is correct.

What tool should we use, if at all?

NOTE: I'm looking for something for C code, although something that works for C++ would be good as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The traditional beautifier [indent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_(Unix)), available on every Unix machine. The version found on some is [GNU indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/), which can be compiled and installed on every machine. GNU indent can read a set of rules from the file `~/.indent.pro`, for instance:

```
--original --dont-format-first-column-comments --no-blank-lines-after-commas --parameter-indentation 8 --indent-level 8 --line-length 85 --no-space-after-parentheses --no-comment-delimiters-on-blank-lines
```

So, just running indent before commiting guarantees uniformity of the presentation. If you want to **enforce** it, define a pre-commit hook in the Version Control System you use, which will run indent and refuse the commit if the committed version differs from what indent produces.

Answer (score 10):

You are looking for a '[code beautifier](http://google.com/search?q=c+code+beautifier)'. [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/)'s a free one.

You only have to be able to describe your coding style in its configuration file, and it'll make sure every file fits the described style.

Answer (score 9):

[AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) does what you want:

> Artistic Style is a source code indenter, formatter, and beautifier for the C, C++, C#  and Java programming languages.

There's an [AStyle Plugin](http://astyleclipse.sourceforge.net/) available for Eclipse.

Eclipse also has a code formatter, but I'm not sure if it works in CDT.

Answer (score 4):

There are (or were) numerous tools for this.  One of the oldest is `cb` (C Beautifier) that was around in ancient versions of Unix - meaning, in this case, Version 7 Unix:

```
CB ( 1 ) UNIX Programmer’s Manual CB ( 1 )

NAME
    cb – C program beautifier
SYNOPSIS
    cb
DESCRIPTION
   Cb places a copy of the C program from the standard input on the standard
   output with spacing and indentation that displays the structure of the
   program.
BUGS
```

GNU `indent` is a vastly more complex and configurable beastie.  There were commercial tools as well.  For example, [Abraxas Software](http://www.abxsoft.com/) provides a CodeCheck tool, for example; we used that briefly in the mid-90s, but the changes it wanted us to make were (very necessary, but) too intrusive for management.

Answer (score 3):

From a similar question: [Vera++](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Home):

> Vera++ is a programmable tool for verification, analysis and
> transformation of C++ source code.
>
> The main usage scenarios that are foreseen for Vera++ are:
>
> Ensure that the source code complies with the given coding standards
> and conventions.
>
> Provide source code metrics and statistics.
>
> Perform automated transformations of the source code, which can range from pretty-printing to diagnostics to fault injection and advanced testing.

Comment: @Tino Tnx for the note, updated (it does seem GitHub is a mirror while the main site is on BitBucket).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `clang-format`. More information can be found at official site:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

I would argue against using a formal tool here. The best enforcement of coding standards is peer pressure. Peer pressure and mutual respect between team members are key elements of that team building environment....no different that the good natured harassing that is necessary when somebody inadvertently "breaks the build", etc.

Review of newer team members' code is a key part of the learning process and integrating into the team and learning the coding standards, etc. If the coding standard is too complicated or subtle to be picked up in this way, then instead of looking for a tool to validate the standard, you should be lookng for a new coding standard.

Comment: That's why I suggest instead a beautifier which will get the files in the required style instead of a validator which will do no good at all. You can code in any style you want and before checking in, you run the beautifier which will make sure fits the requirements.

Comment: @Vinko - You could do that, and it might be helpful to part time contributors or importing external code, but for full time team members, I really do believe you want them all to be "thinking in coding standard" so that you get the real benefit of having a coding standard in the first place.

Comment: Can't agree more. Code review and well defince coding standards should do the work.

Comment: My view is that no coding standard should ever be enforced in any way if there is not a beautifier available to force conformance.  I have my own beautifier rules that I use for all code manipulation, then I generally revert the code to whatever standard my customer prefers to have their code presented in.  An unfortunate side effect of this is that non-printing changes often turn up on check-in when previous submitters failed to comply the standard and the reviewers missed it.

Comment: @jwdonahue Thanks for the additional perspective. Most of my thinking pertains to dedicated team members over the longer term. You raise a good point relative to supporting a variety of standards, each specific to a customer while still being able to support the one you prefer. There, some automation is certainly going to be helpful, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Try [UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/), which is a GUI wrapper around popular indenters/beautifiers such as Uncrustify, Artistic Style, and GNU Indent. Its GUI and live preview function make it very easy to try different indenters, and once you've found an indenter and config you like, you can export the config or even export a shell script. Great if you're still trying things out.

Answer (score -8):

Please use VIM and enjoy the easiness.
You can do anything related to source programming by simple commands.
Also you can make the VIM more reliable and powerful by editing .vimrc file.
The help in it will help you a lot.

/renjith g

Comment: You are being downvoted because the original question was about code pretty printer or a style checker.
And you are answering with a text editor.

The difference is that the text editor is where you write code, and a style checker checks the format of the source code independently of the text editor that was used.

for example this is a style checker: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkstyle