# Rearranging badly styled C code

Tags: c, coding-style

I've got around 12,000 lines of badly styled C code, e.g.

```
initholeend=(mm_footer *) (end-sizeof(mm_footer));
initholeend->magic=MM_MAGIC;
initholestart->used+=amount;
```

What I'd like to do is automatically adding spaces around all binary operands and assigments:

```
initholeend = (mm_footer *) (end - sizeof(mm_footer));
initholeend->magic = MM_MAGIC;
initholestart->used += amount;
```

Is there any recommended tool to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If using Unix, see what `indent` utility can do for you first.

Comment: possible duplicates: [Coding style checker for C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411249/coding-style-checker-for-c), [Code formatter / beautifier for C on Linux for Emacs user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609805/code-formatter-beautifier-for-c-on-linux-for-emacs-user)

Comment: *"do I have use a artillery of regex"* As a general rule regexp are the pop-guns of parsing, and in particular they are not powerful enough to understand c syntax (which does, after all, support nested structures). You might get away with it in this case, but only becuase your use case is so simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) isn't bad.

Comment: for f in $(find -iname "*.c"); do astyle -p $f; done made my day.

Comment: Hours of pain, condensed into less than a minute (?), in one line of shell code. Elegance. :)

Comment: Far less than a minute. Faster than I thought. btw i've had to add -t since it screwed up my indents.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to recommend you [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/). I am quite satisfied with that code beautifier and provides good results for even more programming languages.

Comment: +1 I use uncrustify and it works well in addition to having a funky name

Comment: This looks useful too (linked to from the uncrustify page): http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Most IDEs (and several command-line options) have an option to "auto-format" code according to a coding style of your choice.  Eclipse is one such IDE.

Comment: +1 for Eclipse.  Eclipse also allows you to customize all kinds of aspects of the code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The classic answer is [indent(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_%28Unix%29).

It has about a billion options, which should handle your requirements

Answer (score 0):

If using unix, just open it up in vi with the autoformat feature turned on. If you're on Windows or Mac, use Codeblocks --or Notepad++ if you don't like IDEs -- where indentation and color coding for paren balancing is the default.