# coding style checker for c (variable names, not indentation)

Tags: c, coding-style, naming-conventions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411249/coding-style-checker-for-c) asks about a coding style checker, but the focus seems to be on indentation and brace placement. GNU indent deals with indentation (which isn't a problem in this code base, amazingly enough).

I'm working with a pile of code that is full of various naming schemes: `camelCase`, `everythingruntogetherinlowercase`, `underscores_as_separators`, `SomeStructsEndWithT`, etc.

I'd like to be able to pick a convention and at least have an automatic check that new changes are in line with the convention.

Is there a good tool for checking naming in C? Something like Python's pep8 checker tool, I don't want a beautifier.

Thanks.

Comment: A couple of regexes might cover this, for most cases. Combine with an existing lexer to ease ignoring everything but identifiers.

Comment: The Linux kernel has a style-checker script written in Perl called checkpatch.pl.  It is under linux/scripts.

Comment: The real problem with what you want to do is that you might do this on a case sensitive language and have two variables with the same letters but different case. You might then end up breaking your code. I would approach this very cautiously.

Comment: @hvanbrug That's precisely why having consistent case style is important, and hence this question; variables that have the same name but different case may be fine for the compiler but will confuse the hell out of human maintainers.

Comment: I agree, and it is really something that needs to be enforced at the beginning of a project rather than half way through (sometimes you don't have a choice though, I know).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Google's [cpplint](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/) (a C++ style checker) can be hacked into submission for checking C like I want.

(I'm still interested in knowing if there are any better checkers out there.)

Answer (score 2):

It is an unorthodox choice, but I'd go with `cxref`, if you are willing to put in half a days work. It is a cross referencer, comes with the source code, it has a clean parser and doesn't build a parse tree. Yet, with a few lines of code you can dump all the variables to examine them, or rewrite them to your favoured style (or if you are as lazy as I am instead of rewriting you could generate replace commands for emacs/sed). I only managed to build it for Mac.

Comment: +1: I think there is a lot to be said for using `cxref` (or, alternatively, `ctags`) to do all the hard parsing work required to extract the variable names. I don't think you'd have to modify either of these programs - just post-process the output using `sed`, `perl`, `python` or whatever script to check compliance with a standard.

Comment: What would be an orthodox choice?

Answer (score 1):

This one has a number of answers already in this thread [Coding style checker for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411249/coding-style-checker-for-c)

from which Vera++ might be the most promising, since most of the other suggestions are *formatters* not *validators*.  There's a webpage about running vera++ at 
https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Running.

There's a download from https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/downloads/vera++-1.1.1.tar.gz
Compiling presents a few issues:

- `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev tcl-dev`
- An include of `tcl.h` that should have been `tcl/tcl.h`
- Need a full boost src tree, like that from http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.53.0/boost_1_53_0.tar.gz/download
- The build command becomes something like: `make BOOST_DIR=/home/fluffy/tmp/boost_1_53_0`
- vera++ needs a `~/.vera++/profiles/` but doesn't autocreate a default (it can be copied from the one in the distribution, however)

Finally, running it on a C++ file produced output like (with duplicate errors omitted for brevity):

```
../dllist.c:1: no copyright notice found
../dllist.c:4: horizontal tab used
../dllist.c:10: horizontal tab used
../dllist.c:10: closing curly bracket not in the same line or column
../dllist.c:29: horizontal tab used
../dllist.c:38: keyword 'if' not followed by a single space
../dllist.c:38: negation operator used in its short form
../dllist.c:40: horizontal tab used
../dllist.c:40: full block {} expected in the control structure
../dllist.c:42: horizontal tab used
../dllist.c:71: keyword 'if' not followed by a single space
../dllist.c:71: negation operator used in its short form
../dllist.c:72: horizontal tab used
../dllist.c:72: full block {} expected in the control structure
../dllist.c:73: horizontal tab used
```

Comment: Does Vera++ check naming style, as per the 2nd sentence in the question? I've checked the [rules in the wiki](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Rules) which didn't mention naming convention checks. Also, the updated link seems to be https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera

Comment: I've added material on how to find, build (and get the build to work), and run the result with an example output.  However, check out the other stackoverflow thread too - you could just use `indent` (as @bortzmeyer suggests) and diff the result for possible style cleanup, which could also be used as a rather draconian git check-in hook.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but _does Vera++ check variable names_? That is, can I configure it to find variables/functions that aren't camelCase, or PascalCase etc? Your expanded answer doesn't cover this, and I don't think GNU indent checks this either.

Comment: It looks like rule `T010` looks at the exact composition of any given identifier, so although it doesn't have a test specifically for camel case, one could be written in Tcl by copying it to a new rule and adding some rexexp. The script is visible at https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/src/37be76ec0b90239da5a687269ae05147312d6d6f/scripts/rules/T010.tcl?at=master