# Running eclipse CDT name style checks headless

Tags: c, eclipse, naming-conventions, headless

I can't find any tool that can be run in an automated way to check for naming convention violations within a `C` project

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/411249/911550) is about a *style* checker. While important, it is not the focus of my question.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5474936/911550) is about *naming* conventions, but the answers given there do not point to a ready-made solution.

Eclipse has buried within its preferences *C/C++ > Code Style > Name Style* a few settings that check for specific names. Is there a way to have those checks executed from the command-line?