# Is there a GCC warning to catch if statement and operation on same line

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

Is there a GCC warning I can turn on that can catch it if I have an if-statement followed by an operation on the same line, like in this example

```
    if ( ReadOnly == accessMode ) readFile();
```

I want to use this to enforce a coding standard.

Comment: Perhaps if you are using an editor like Visual Studio Code you can enable a plugin that enforces that?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could use regular expressions to find those lines.

Comment: Agree with above. If you have a line that starts with `if` and ends with a semicolon you have something to look at either way.

Comment: That is a "style" preference rather than a coding standard.  To the compiler the white-space preference has no semantic impact, so it is not the responsibility of the compiler to enforce.  There are plenty of tools that will either check or enforce style preferences.  Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411249/coding-style-checker-for-c is relevant, but it is an old question, Google for current tools.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a gcc warning, since that line is perfectly legal in either C or C++. In Linux, you can use the grep command to find these lines in your .cpp files.

```
grep -n -e "^\s\+if(.*;$" -e "^\s\+if\s\+(.*;$" *.cpp
```

Or simply

```
grep -n "^\s\+if\s\{0,3\}(.*;$" *.cpp
```

The $ in the above line means end-of-line, can be removed to match more results.

^ matches start-of-line.
\s\+ matches one or more spaces.
\s\{0,3\} match 0 to 3 spaces.
.* matches everything.

The above grep commands don't find break lines, such as

```
if( readOnly == access )
        readFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to enforce a coding "standard", like some kind of coding style, I would suggest to use a tool for that purpose.

The compiler, although being able to emit diagnostics for some "code smells", they are usually related to code behavior, possible UB or other misuses of the language, not so related to coding style. For instance, it can emit a diagnostics for the following "style" misuse:

```
if (x)
  doSomething();
  doSomethingElse();  //Diagnostic: this line is not protected by the if.
```

But these diagnostics are limited to very few very obviously wrong code.

Regexes, while probably solving your current issue, will fall short for a general style enforcement.

So, I think the ideal way would be to use a tool designed for enforcing coding style. There are plenty of such tools. I would suggest either:

- clang-format: widely used and supported.
- [uncrustify](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify): tons of options to define your own style.

In most editors you can enable them to be run "on saving", restyling your code to fit your style.

Answer (score 0):

As LoPiTaL suggests, use a tool designed to enforce coding standards. The compiler is ill-suited for this purpose.

For your specific ask, `clang-format` has the option `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine` that you can use.

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, "No, there is no such command line option."